# Accounts.sendVerificationEmail Issue in Meteor

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I Need to send VerificationEmail using `Meteor`.I did the code but It didn't send VerificationEmail and also got error on server side.Error is : **Can't find user**.I didn't have any idea about this.so Please see the below code & suggest me how to do.

JS Code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
 Template.main.events
  ({
    'submit #register-form' : function (e,t)
     {

            console.log("You pressed the button Register ");
            e.preventDefault();
           var username = t.find('#username').value
            , name = t.find('#name').value
            , email = t.find('#email1').value
            , password = t.find('#pwd1').value;
            console.log("password="+password);

             var isValidPassword = function(val, field)
             {
                if (val.length >= 6) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  Session.set('displayMessage', 'Error &amp; Too short.')
                  return false; 
                }
             }

             if (isValidPassword(password))
             {
                console.log(" *** isValidPassword *** ");
                Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password,username : username }, function(err)
                {
                   if (err) 
                    {
                      console.log(err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       console.log("Register Successfully");

                         Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                        '*****@gmail.com',
                        '****.com',
                        'Hello from Meteor!',
                        'This is a test of Email.send.');


                    }
                });
             }
             else
             {
                console.log("*** Error ***");
             }
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function ()
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  //Meteor methods

   Meteor.methods
  ({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) 
  {
     Accounts.config({sendVerificationEmail: true, forbidClientAccountCreation: false}); 
     process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://****@gmail.com:*pwd*@smtp.gmail.com:587';

    this.unblock();

    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(to);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the email to an email address? When you use `to` in `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(to);`

it must be the `_id` of the user you want to send the confirmation email to, not their email address.

Comment: Which ID i can given here that is i confused so please give me guidence?@Akshat.

Comment: The `_id` of the user in the user's collection. Also visible with `Meteor.userId` or `Meteor.user()._id`. Meteor needs to know what user you want to confirm in the email and it uses the `_id` to identify them.

Comment: Okay.And i have raised another doubt i.e I am using to send verification mail when ever register a user . User ID was Not Changed to Register More users in same page.so  in this time i got one error i.e "Error : Can't set `sendVerificationEmail` more than once".But the mail was sent.@Akshat

Comment: I have changed to the code below :                                  var ID = Meteor.userId();
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(ID);.So UserId gets One Registered User Per One id or not? Can you please give me guidence for this.@Akshat

Comment: And Register More than One user at the same page this i got error in client side i.e "Error : Internal server error [500]".how to do?.@Akshat